# Can an access point redirect outgoing ping requests from clients?

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking

I have a raspberry media server that creates a wifi hotspot (without internet bridge) using hostapd and dnsmasq.

One of the devices that connects to it is a little stubborn and disconnects from the wifi if it doesn't receive a ping response from 8.8.8.8.

Is there a way for the media server to intercept and respond to the ping request so it doesn't disconnect from the network?